# admin auth check not working

Tags: cakephp, routes, admin, authentication

for my client's website I have an admin section- only thing is my admin routing doesn't seem to be password protected. I added the admin protection with a tutorial on how to set up a user system, and have placed the following code in app_controller.php:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    // if an admin route is requested and not logged in
    $user = $this->Session->read('User');
    if(isset($this->params['admin']) && $this->params['admin'] && is_null($user)) {
        // set Flash and redirect to login page
        $this->Session->setFlash('You need to be logged in for that action.','default',array('class'=>'flash_bad'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>FALSE));
    }
}
```

& in my app/config/routes.php I have this:

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));  
Router::connect('/admin/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

which I'm pretty sure is missing something for the protection.

I can still access other admin areas without logging in though, i.e. theowlhouse.com.au/admin/bookings.

What am I doing wrong? The admin page for the users model is the only protected one.

Thanks :)

Comment: what tutorial did you use? can you post a link?

Comment: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing) with using the [auth component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication).  Note that prefix routing was called 'admin routing' prior to version 1.3.

You don't need to use admin routing to use the auth component. Let's start with just getting the auth component set up.  In your app controller, make sure you have it included in your components array:

```
var $components = array('Auth');
```

Once you've done that, users will be directed to a login page unless they are logged in.  To allow anonymous users to access an action, you make a called to `$this->Auth->allow('action name');`  So, for example, say you want to allow unauthenticated users to use the index() and view() actions in your items controller, but not add() or edit(). In your items_controller.php, you would set up the beforeFilter() to make a call:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(array(
        'index',
        'view'
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks tyler,

So I take it I scrap the other before filter? and do I scrap the admin_ prefixes to the admin functions? Does cakephp already know that the Users model is to be used for authentication?

Also, I can't see anything wrong with your syntax, but when I changed the beforeFilter, I get an unexpected T operator error.

Comment: Correct, you should replace the beforeFilter.  Correct, you don't need to use the 'admin_' prefixes.  Correct the Auth component defaults to using the User model.  I've edited my code above, as it was missing a > and a closing parenthesis.

Comment: thankyou for getting back to me- firstly I've changed my app_controller beforeFilter() to updated login auth, however I'm curious as to how I'd go about having an index for a controller and an admin_index... can I just put it in anyway?
my problem just lies in getting login to work- something is just not going right. it's pretty interesting actually, but I'll ask otherwhere. I think once I get that working your help will make it go seamlessly. thanks heaps dude.